# Read configuration section in WebApplication scoped code with CAS

Tags: 2010, security, configuration

I'm testing some code here, trying to get it to work with CAS. I have a configuration file at a file location with some WCF definitions. I load this code with:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"C:\path\client.config");
```

which works just fine. I can also load it with `File.ReadAllText(...)`, as I've added the CAS permissions to read the file. However when I call:

```
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
```

I get a security exception that I'm not allowed to read the section. Is there a way around this without modifying machine.config. The config class is passed to a WCF proxy class.

My other option is to recreate the WCF proxy class, reading the .config file as xml and manually set all the properties A lot more work.

Or I'll give up and just GAC it instead. But I hate to give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reflectored the ConfigSection class for the client section of the servicemodel section. The GetSection method of this class has the `SecurityCriticalAttribute` applied to it. This means (according to the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute.aspx)):

> The SecurityCriticalAttribute is
>   equivalent to a link demand for full
>   trust. A type or member marked with
>   the SecurityCriticalAttribute can be
>   called only by fully trusted code; it
>   does not have to demand specific
>   permissions. It cannot be called by
>   partially trusted code.

Comment: Thanks Coling! As I've spent all day in Reflector, how on earth did I miss this :) And guess it would be pretty hard to omit this even with reflection trickery.